# How to import .java library in IntelliJ (folder of .java files)

Tags: java, intellij-idea

I am a new programmer.

Here, I am trying to import a library ([com.digitalmodular](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/13260068/com.digitalmodular.zip)).

What I want to do is run the java program in [here](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/22144/images-with-all-colors)

```
package demos;

import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Arrays;

import com.digitalmodular.utilities.RandomFunctions;
import com.digitalmodular.utilities.gui.ImageFunctions;
import com.digitalmodular.utilities.swing.window.PixelImage;
import com.digitalmodular.utilities.swing.window.PixelWindow;

/**
 * @author jeronimus
 */
// Date 2014-02-28
public class AllColorDiffusion extends PixelWindow implements Runnable {
    private static final int    CHANNEL_BITS    = 7;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int bits = CHANNEL_BITS * 3;
        int heightBits = bits / 2;
        int widthBits = bits - heightBits;

        new AllColorDiffusion(CHANNEL_BITS, 1 << widthBits, 1 << heightBits);
    }

    private final int           width;
    private final int           height;
    private final int           channelBits;
    private final int           channelSize;

    private PixelImage          img;
    private javax.swing.Timer   timer;

    private boolean[]           colorCube;
    private long[]              foundColors;
    private boolean[]           queued;
    private int[]               queue;
    private int                 queuePointer    = 0;
    private int                 remaining;

    public AllColorDiffusion(int channelBits, int width, int height) {
        super(1024, 1024 * height / width);

        RandomFunctions.RND.setSeed(0);

        this.width = width;
        this.height = height;
        this.channelBits = channelBits;
        channelSize = 1 << channelBits;
    }

    @Override
    public void initialized() {
        img = new PixelImage(width, height);

        colorCube = new boolean[channelSize * channelSize * channelSize];
        foundColors = new long[channelSize * channelSize * channelSize];
        queued = new boolean[width * height];
        queue = new int[width * height];
        for (int i = 0; i < queue.length; i++)
            queue[i] = i;

        new Thread(this).start();
    }

    @Override
    public void resized() {}

    @Override
    public void run() {
        timer = new javax.swing.Timer(500, new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                draw();
            }
        });

        while (true) {
            img.clear(0);
            init();
            render();
        }

        // System.exit(0);
    }

    private void init() {
        RandomFunctions.RND.setSeed(0);

        Arrays.fill(colorCube, false);
        Arrays.fill(queued, false);
        remaining = width * height;

        // Initial seeds (need to be the darkest colors, because of the darkest
        // neighbor color search algorithm.)
        setPixel(width / 2 + height / 2 * width, 0);
        remaining--;
    }

    private void render() {
        timer.start();

        for (; remaining > 0; remaining--) {
            int point = findPoint();
            int color = findColor(point);
            setPixel(point, color);
        }

        timer.stop();
        draw();

        try {
            ImageFunctions.savePNG(System.currentTimeMillis() + ".png", img.image);
        }
        catch (IOException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    void draw() {
        g.drawImage(img.image, 0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight(), 0, 0, width, height, null);
        repaintNow();
    }

    private int findPoint() {
        while (true) {
            // Time to reshuffle?
            if (queuePointer == 0) {
                for (int i = queue.length - 1; i > 0; i--) {
                    int j = RandomFunctions.RND.nextInt(i);
                    int temp = queue[i];
                    queue[i] = queue[j];
                    queue[j] = temp;
                    queuePointer = queue.length;
                }
            }

            if (queued[queue[--queuePointer]])
                return queue[queuePointer];
        }
    }

    private int findColor(int point) {
        int x = point & width - 1;
        int y = point / width;

        // Calculate the reference color as the average of all 8-connected
        // colors.
        int r = 0;
        int g = 0;
        int b = 0;
        int n = 0;
        for (int j = -1; j <= 1; j++) {
            for (int i = -1; i <= 1; i++) {
                point = (x + i & width - 1) + width * (y + j & height - 1);
                if (img.pixels[point] != 0) {
                    int pixel = img.pixels[point];

                    r += pixel >> 24 - channelBits & channelSize - 1;
                    g += pixel >> 16 - channelBits & channelSize - 1;
                    b += pixel >> 8 - channelBits & channelSize - 1;
                    n++;
                }
            }
        }
        r /= n;
        g /= n;
        b /= n;

        // Find a color that is preferably darker but not too far from the
        // original. This algorithm might fail to take some darker colors at the
        // start, and when the image is almost done the size will become really
        // huge because only bright reference pixels are being searched for.
        // This happens with a probability of 50% with 6 channelBits, and more
        // with higher channelBits values.
        //
        // Try incrementally larger distances from reference color.
        for (int size = 2; size <= channelSize; size *= 2) {
            n = 0;

            // Find all colors in a neighborhood from the reference color (-1 if
            // already taken).
            for (int ri = r - size; ri <= r + size; ri++) {
                if (ri < 0 || ri >= channelSize)
                    continue;
                int plane = ri * channelSize * channelSize;
                int dr = Math.abs(ri - r);
                for (int gi = g - size; gi <= g + size; gi++) {
                    if (gi < 0 || gi >= channelSize)
                        continue;
                    int slice = plane + gi * channelSize;
                    int drg = Math.max(dr, Math.abs(gi - g));
                    int mrg = Math.min(ri, gi);
                    for (int bi = b - size; bi <= b + size; bi++) {
                        if (bi < 0 || bi >= channelSize)
                            continue;
                        if (Math.max(drg, Math.abs(bi - b)) > size)
                            continue;
                        if (!colorCube[slice + bi])
                            foundColors[n++] = Math.min(mrg, bi) << channelBits * 3 | slice + bi;
                    }
                }
            }

            if (n > 0) {
                // Sort by distance from origin.
                Arrays.sort(foundColors, 0, n);

                // Find a random color amongst all colors equally distant from
                // the origin.
                int lowest = (int)(foundColors[0] >> channelBits * 3);
                for (int i = 1; i < n; i++) {
                    if (foundColors[i] >> channelBits * 3 > lowest) {
                        n = i;
                        break;
                    }
                }

                int nextInt = RandomFunctions.RND.nextInt(n);
                return (int)(foundColors[nextInt] & (1 << channelBits * 3) - 1);
            }
        }

        return -1;
    }

    private void setPixel(int point, int color) {
        int b = color & channelSize - 1;
        int g = color >> channelBits & channelSize - 1;
        int r = color >> channelBits * 2 & channelSize - 1;
        img.pixels[point] = 0xFF000000 | ((r << 8 | g) << 8 | b) << 8 - channelBits;

        colorCube[color] = true;

        int x = point & width - 1;
        int y = point / width;
        queued[point] = false;
        for (int j = -1; j <= 1; j++) {
            for (int i = -1; i <= 1; i++) {
                point = (x + i & width - 1) + width * (y + j & height - 1);
                if (img.pixels[point] == 0) {
                    queued[point] = true;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The thing is, I cant figure out how to import the library into IntelliJ. I have tried importing the library from Project Structure->Modules->Dependencies->Library->Java but failed. It appears that all the files in the given library are .java files, not .jar files

How should I import the library? Do I need to compile the whole library first? If yes, how?

This is my first question on this site, so my question may not be so clear :P

Answer (score 0):

try
go to project settings -> Platform Settings -> SDKs -> Sourcepath (in the right panel) and add your downloaded zip -> Apply -> OK

Comment: It appears that nothing has happened after I added the zip file into the sourcepath. I add it, and it then tells me that the project SDK is not defined